# System.Net.Http.HttpClient returns error "ERR: Missing UA30"

Tags: c#, .net, f#, httpclient, icalendar

The following code gives me the rather strange error `ERR: Missing UA30` in the response content. I can't find the error anywhere on the Internet. It only happens to some particular websites.
There is another version of the code testing serveral `ics` URLs simultaneously on [this repo](https://github.com/kumkee/IcsDownloadTest/).
Since F# and C# share the same framework, I suspect this would happen to C# as well but I haven't tested it as my C# is not as fluent.

```ml
open System.Net.Http

let url = "https://portal.macleans.school.nz/index.php/ics/school.ics"
(* other working urls:
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/DeMarko/6142417/raw/1cd301a5917141524b712f92c2e955e86a1add19/sample.ics"
    "https://www.kayaposoft.com/enrico/ics/v2.0?country=gbr&fromDate=01-01-2023&toDate=31-12-2023&region=eng"
    "https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/download/1/file/63438/name/example.ics"
    *)


let getAsync (client: HttpClient) (url: string) =
    async {
        let! content = client.GetStringAsync url |> Async.AwaitTask
        let len = content.Length
        printf "%d" len

        match len with
        | len when len < 50 -> printfn " content: %s" content
        | _ -> printfn ""
    }

let client = new HttpClient()

getAsync client url
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

All what I've tried have been documented in the GitHub repo mentioned above.

I am expecting no error as `curl` command is able to download the `ics` file without problems -

```bash
curl https://portal.macleans.school.nz/index.php/ics/school.ics -o output.ics
```

Comment: Where does that message appear?  As the content of the response or as an exception?  If the latter, please add a stack trace.

Comment: @Fooe Within the content of the response.

Comment: The error is most likely coming from the server and would happen with any http client.  Alternatively it could be coming from a proxy between you and the server.

Comment: @Foole curl or Chrome doesn't give any errors

Comment: My next guess would be the request headers.  They will differ between dotnet and chrome/curl.  A logging proxy like Telerik Fiddler would help diagnose this.

Comment: @Foole I have the same guess but I am not familiar with any logging proxy. I'll give the open-source alternative `mitmproxy` a try.

Comment: @Foole you are right. It turns out that the server rejects any requests without a User-Agnet value. Problem solved. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set user agent setting header in your HTTP request.
for example :

```ml
open System.Net.Http

let url = "https://portal.macleans.school.nz/index.php/ics/school.ics"

let getAsync (client: HttpClient) (url: string) =
    async {
        let request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url)
        request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "NonEmptyUA")

        let! response = client.SendAsync(request) |> Async.AwaitTask
        let content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        printfn "Response content length: %d" (content.Length)

        if content.Length < 50 then
            printfn "Response content: %s" content
    }

let client = new HttpClient()

getAsync client url
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```